# Codeigniter pass variables to to multiple controller functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to add the following code to multiple functions without retyping the code individually?

```
$user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
$data['row'] = $this->Profile_model->profile_read($user_id);
```

I tried putting the variables in the constructor but I get undefined variables for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could turn it in to a private function of the controller, i.e.

```
private function get_user_id()
{
    $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
    return $this->Profile_model->profile_read($user_id);
}
```

And then in every function in your controller do:

```
$data['row'] = $this->get_user_id();
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm just wondering why are you using `protected` and not `private` ?

Comment: Hah - sorry I meant private! Need sleep :)

Comment: Heh no problem :) I was just thinking if `protected` offers a greater advantage.

Answer (score 1):

It only saves you one line but thats a 100% decrease in code lines!

```
private function rowData(){
  $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
  return $this->Profile_model->profile_read($user_id);
}

$data['row'] = $this->rowData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you put it in the constructor you'd need:

```
$this->user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
$this->data['row'] = $this->Profile_model->profile_read($user_id);
```

Comment: thanks I tried but I get `Cannot access empty property` for both

Answer (score 0):

You can have this as the controller's constructor:

```
class Example extends CI_Controller {

   protected $user_id;

   function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->load->model('Profile_model');

        $this->user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
        $data['row'] = $this->Profile_model->profile_read($this->user_id);

        $this->load->vars($data);
   }

}
```

and you will have access to $row in any subsequent views loaded from that constructor, as well as be able to use $this->user_id in any of the functions of that controller.

Source: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: Thanks, I had tried putting the code in constructor but I get undefined variable for `$user_id` wherever I try to use it in controller functions.

Comment: Check the change to the example, use $this->user_id in any of the controller functions you are looking to use it in, and then $row in any of the views. Is that what you're looking to do?

Answer (score -2):

Did you load the tank_auth library or set it to autoload?